# How can I merge and line up (or put an order) two different length data frame according to their code number in R

Tags: r

I have 2 different data frames.
In Df3, there are data of 86 meals with different meal_number.
In Df4 includes 10 more meals data (96 meals) but same meals with Df3 have same meal-numbers in Df4. Df4 also includes the meal types (breakfast, Lunch, Dinner).

```
>  Df3[45:55,]    
     Meal_Number             GluTime  Gluc Meal_Number  n
1.44           1 2019-10-26 12:18:00 9.104           1 49
1.45           1 2019-10-26 12:23:00 9.104           1 49
1.46           1 2019-10-26 12:28:00 9.104           1 49
1.47           1 2019-10-26 12:33:00 8.937           1 49
1.48           1 2019-10-26 12:38:00 8.826           1 49
2              3 2019-10-26 21:18:00 7.994           3 50
2.1            3 2019-10-26 21:23:00 7.994           3 50
2.2            3 2019-10-26 21:28:00 8.216           3 50
2.3            3 2019-10-26 21:33:00 8.771           3 50
2.4            3 2019-10-26 21:38:00 8.771           3 50
2.5            3 2019-10-26 21:43:00 8.382           3 50

>  Df4[45:55,]      
     Meal_Type Meal_4h Meal_Number
1.44 Breakfast   Inc_M           1
1.45 Breakfast   Inc_M           1
1.46 Breakfast   Inc_M           1
1.47 Breakfast   Inc_M           1
1.48 Breakfast   Inc_M           1
2        Lunch   Inc_M           2
2.1      Lunch   Inc_M           2
2.2      Lunch   Inc_M           2
```

I need to learn that 86 meals (Df3) are which kind of meal type and create a new df. So, I planned to merge of these 2 df. I was repeated the categorizing of the meal type (in Df4) exactly same glucose value times (for example during 4 hours, if there are 45 glucose value, lunch was repeated 45 times). But I couldn't merge them. My code didn't work. Could you tell me what is wrong?

```
> Df4 <- Df3 %>% filter(Df3$Meal_Number==D$Meal_Number,.by=Meal_Number)

Error in `filter()`:
! Names must be unique.
✖ These names are duplicated:
* "Meal_Number" at locations 1 and 2.
```

Many many thanks for your help..

Comment: I think you need `%in%` instead of `==`. Also `.by` seems unnecessary. Try `Df4 <- Df3 %>% filter(Meal_Number %in% unique(D$Meal_Number))`

Comment: Merging is usually done with the `merge()` function or the `*_join()` functions in `dplyr`. Looks like `Df4` has a bunch of duplicate rows, I would remove those and join, `Df3 %>% left_join(unique(Df4), by = "Meal_Number")`